# EJB Lite classes are not available on project classpath

Tags: java, netbeans, vaadin

I'm having problem generating "Session Beans for Entity Classes" in Netbeans 8.0.2. I'm using Vaadin 7.3.6 framework via Maven, MySQL and Glassfish v4.

error:

```
Cannot be generated because EJB Lite classes are not available on project classpath.
```

What is the solution to this?

Comment: Please describe more about the problem you are facing... Based on error message displayed I can straight forward say that your project has some classpath issues

Comment: @Patton, This is the only detail that Netbeans IDE has provided me. http://www.imagesup.net/?di=10142336478912

Answer (score 3):

I keep on trying different EJB API's but with no success until I tried creating a WEB Application using JSF Framework and followed the steps I did with Vaadin and it works. I compared both dependencies and found that JSF is using javax.ejb-api.jar so I search and download the API via maven for my Vaadin and VOILA! I can now create "Session Beans for Entity Classes" without error.

Problem Solved.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans needs to have proper dependencies and persistence.xml settings configured to make that feature work. Typically you should have e.g. Java EE 7 API in your pom.xml like this:

```
<dependency>  
  <groupId>javax</groupId>    
  <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>    
  <version>7.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then ensure you have the datasource configured in your development server and define that as the target server for your project. Then both this and the awesome "Entity classes from database" feature should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Right now, Im struggling to connect to my DB (MySQL). Im having a java.lang.NullPointerException. Maybe there's something wrong in my persistence.xml configuration but I think this should be posted on a different thread after I run out of ideas to solve it. ^_^