# NetBeans 15 Cannot be generated because EJB Lite classes are not available on project classpath

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, glassfish, persistence

I'm trying to create Persistence `New JSF Pages from Entity Classes` using NetBeans 15, Java Web Project with Ant.

I get this error:

```
Cannot be generated because EJB Lite classes are not available on project classpath
```

[image]

I was able to create Persistence `Entity Classes from Database`. My glassfish database is running and I can view data in my tables.

My project properties:

- Server: GlassFish Server
- Java EE Version: Jakarta EE 9.1 Web - I cannot select another version when I create a new project.

Comment: Add those JARs to your project.  Just like solving any other CLASSPATH issue.  Just curious: Why EJB?  It's a failed 90s era technology.  Most people have moved on to POJOs using Spring Boot.  https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&geo=US&q=ejb,spring%20boot

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding the jar but it did not work. It's not my choice. I have no idea why it's an error. I have to use NetBeans + Ant to create a web project.

Comment: I only know how to use Maven but it's not an option in this case.

Comment: Both NetBeans and Ant are old and out of date.  Who gave you this project?

Comment: my professor  please don't ask, it'll just inflict more pain...

Comment: Professors are always teaching what they learned; generals are always fighting the last war.  https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html

Comment: I'm guessing that you didn't give NetBeans the heads up that this is a Glassfish EJB project.

Comment: It's not EJB project. It's just the error. When I used NetBeans 14, I followed the same steps and got to the failed deploy without EJB.

Comment: "Cannot be generated because EJB Lite classes are not available on project classpath" - believe NetBeans.  It can't find EJB classes.  Do you know how to add JARs to the CLASSPATH in NetBeans?

Comment: Ask your professor.  Show him/her the error and ask for help.

Comment: @duffymo people who know more than you and I about Java would disagree about EJB and Netbeans being outdated... Adam Bien has no issue using both.

Comment: I think the marketplace has spoken.  JEE and EJB are done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why, but adding these to the project's `Libraries` solved it for me: **Jakarta EE 9 API Library** and **Java EE 7 API Library**.

This help me move past the error but my application is not working due to other errors.

Comment: [1] FYI, see [EJB Lite classes are not available on project classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28382544/2985643) from 2015 for a similar issue when using Vaadin and NetBeans. The solution for that question was the same as yours. However, since that question was for a Maven project and you have an Ant project your question is not a duplicate of that one. [2] Also, could you please accept your answer here since it obviously solved your problem? Accepted answers are more helpful for the SO community.